# Struts Date Tag Event

Tags: javascript, jsp, jsp-tags

I have a Struts custom date tag being used in our application. I need to fire an event when ever there is change in the date and perform an operation. I tried onchange/onkeyup/onkeydown events.

```
<s:date property="data(date)" disabled="false" todayButtonDisabled="true" id="date" />
```

But it throws me an error as below

```
Failed to compile JSP /jsp/tiles/date.jsp date.jsp:428:28: This attribute is not recognized.
                id="date" onkeypress="DateCheck(this)"
```

Do we have any events which can handle the onchange events for this date custom tag?

Answer (score 0):

The more common way is not to use any on* attributes in the html-code and use javascript to add (javascript-)actions to events. I hope your customtag allows the class-attribute:

```
<s:date property="data(date)" disabled="false" todayButtonDisabled="true" id="date" class="dateelements"/>
```

And e.g. with jQuery:

```
$('.dateelements').on('keydown', function(evt) {
    //dosomething
});
```

Or you could change the customtag definition (should be some tld-file in your project) to allow the on* events. There is a option `<dynamic-attributes>true</dynamic-attributes>` which should be working.